# Resize window in vim with a keyboard map

Tags: vim

I am trying to set the `+` and `_` keys to increase or decrease the size of a window pane in vim. Here is what I have so far in my `.vimrc`:

```
 nnoremap + :res +5
 nnoremap _ :res -5
```

However it doesn't appear to work. What would be the proper way to map the resize pane in vim? Also, is there a way to press `[enter]` automatically after entering the command so that it executes automatically?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `:res` commands are fine, but you need to append `<CR>` (for Carriage Return) to the mappings to actually execute them when you press <kbd>+</kbd> or  <kbd>_</kbd> . So, your mappings should look like this:

```vim
nnoremap + :res +5<CR>
nnoremap _ :res -5<CR>
```

It should be noted that there are built-in hotkeys in Vim to increase and decrease the window height and width, with the default number being 1:

- Increase height (by 1): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>
- Decrease height (by 1): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>
- Increase width (by 1): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>></kbd>
- Decrease width (by 1): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd><</kbd>

To use the above hotkeys with values other than 1, simply prepend the hotkey with the value:

- Increase height by 5: <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>

Comment: If desired to change the vertical size aswell,  the command is `:vertical res +10`, kinda straight forward but just for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: use a "mode" where normal arrow keys can resize the current window.
either map to `+` or
`:call ToggleResizeMode()`

```
"
" + toggle remap arrow keys to resize windows
"
nnoremap + :call ToggleResizeMode()<CR>

let s:KeyResizeEnabled = 0

function! ToggleResizeMode()
  if s:KeyResizeEnabled
    call NormalArrowKeys()
    let s:KeyResizeEnabled = 0
  else
    call ResizeArrowKeys()
    let s:KeyResizeEnabled = 1
  endif
endfunction

function! NormalArrowKeys()
  " unmap arrow keys
  echo 'normal arrow keys'
  nunmap <Up>
  nunmap <Down>
  nunmap <Left>
  nunmap <Right>
endfunction

function! ResizeArrowKeys()
  " Remap arrow keys to resize window
  echo 'Resize window with arrow keys'
  nnoremap <Up>    :resize +2<CR>
  nnoremap <Down>  :resize -2<CR>
  nnoremap <Left>  :vertical resize -2<CR>
  nnoremap <Right> :vertical resize +2<CR>
endfunction
```

Or better: someone already implemented a window submode, there is probably a plugin for it somewhere.
https://ddrscott.github.io/blog/2016/making-a-window-submode/